# How to Replace several words in one string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to replace several different specific words/values in one string, for example:

`1)`, `2)`, `3)`, `A.`, `B.`, `C.`, etc.

They can all be replaced with the same thing - nothing, i.e. no value entered into the replace box.

But I need to do it without Notepad++ deleting any individual aspects of the "words." For example, it should delete `1)`, `2)`, `A.`, `B.` without deleting any individual value like `1`, `2` (numbers on their own), `)` (parenthesis on their own), `A`, `B` (letters on their own) or `.` (periods on their own).

So far I tried entering this into the find box:

```
(1.)|(2.)|(3.)|(A.)|(B.)|(C.)
```

But it deleted every single number `1`, `2` or `3`, every period and every capital `A`, `B` or `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
([1-3]|[A-C])(\.|\))
```

You basically ignored the fact that there are special characters like `.` (any character) and `)` (closing of a group) that need to be escaped in regexes. You can also group characters with `[A-C]` syntax, which means `A` to `C`.

[Demo with step by step explantation](https://regex101.com/r/U3XZLN/2)

If you need all numbers starting from `1` and capital characters (so typical simple enumeration) then you can replace with:

```
([1-9]\d*|[A-Z])(\.|\))
```

Where `\d*` is just shorthand for `[0-9]*`, so optional multiple digits, following a number that's not `0` (`[1-9]`).

With Roman numerals as per comment (not necessarily valid ones):

```
([1-9]\d*|[A-Z]|[CDILMVX]+)(\.|\))
```

So basically just repeating valid characters in a character group.
If ou need tocheck for valid ones then searchingis your friend and this is a random example of a [complex regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/7264739) that you need to add as alternative.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was looking for, thank you! How do I also get this to work with Roman numerals as well, any ideas?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have any idea how it can be done with Roman numerals?

Comment: Ok great, thank you! Is there any way to get rid of the space that it leaves at the beginning of each line?

Comment: I don't know which space. Once again, not specified in the question.

Comment: I want the values that are to be replaced simply deleted, when I run the code in the find box, it deletes those values great, but it replaces them with a blank space at the beginning of every line.

It should just delete the value (replacing it with nothing).

Comment: Add new lines at either start or end to the match in that case.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's basic regex modification - `\n` is new line (or `\r\n` to be more accurate in Windows), you want it either at start or end. Please don't turn this into a discussion forum with further requests as this makes your question worse and worse. Any requirements should be in that in the future, together with your attempts at solving them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
^(\d+|[A-Z])\)
```

This regular expression can be broken down as follows:

```
^: This asserts the position at the start of a line.
(: This opens a capturing group.
\d+: This matches one or more digits (0-9).
|: This is the alternation operator, working like an OR in regular expressions.
[A-Z]: This matches a single uppercase letter from A to Z.
): This closes the capturing group.
\) : This matches a closing parenthesis.
```

So, this regular expression will match any string that starts with one or more digits (0-9) or a single uppercase letter (A-Z), followed by a closing parenthesis. Some examples of matching strings would be:

```
"1)"
"23)"
"A)"
"Z)"
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that for periods (1. 2. 3. A. B. C.) as well?